# How to calculate the Intersect of a ggplot line and a nonlinear function in r

Tags: r, intersection, non-linear-regression

INTRO: I am new to r and to stack overflow...So I am doing a term paper and need to run some stats on how or better when to develop habits.
Ideally habit formation is according to Mitscherlich’s law & looks like a non-linear regression and a asymptote. Once a participant reaches his plateau (defined as 95% interval to asymptote) One can speak of an established habit... Well actually that is debateable... BUT we are doing a replica of a study done by Lally et al. 2010 (How habits are formed:Modelling habit formation in the real world) So we somehow have to stick to certian criteria

ACTUAL QUESTION: The first step is to obtain the R2 for linear and non-linear regression. This I managed.
But for some reason I just can not manage to obtain the x-Axis value for the intersect(orange point in picture) of a non-linear function and my 95% Habit plateau line (Purple line in picture)...
[Here is an example of how an ideal graph looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsrtN.png)

But exactley this X value is crucial for group comparison and later on checking for significant differences...

Of course I already googled but somehow I could not manage to make sense of the presented solutions to other or similar question... It seems one can not do it in ggplot with the **geom_point()** & therefore has to build a seperate formula using the **approx()** function, right?

Maybe someone can help me out... Tks in advance!

And here is the code of interest...

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(stats)


days <- c(0:15)
score <- c(14,17,16,22,24,27,30,31,32,35,40,43,42,43,43)


df <- data.frame(days,score)




# red curve in graph
#This way the R2 for the nonlinear regression is obtained for later analisis

nonlinreg1 <- nls(score ~ SSasymp(days, Asym, R0, lrc), data = df)
summary(nonlinreg1)
RSS <- sum(residuals(nonlinreg1)^2)
TSS <- sum((df$score - mean(df$score))^2)
R.square.nonlinreg1 <- 1 - (RSS/TSS)
R.square.nonlinreg1

# purple line in graph
#Definition of plateau at 95% of asymptote reached

Asymp95 <- summary(nonlinreg1)$parameters[1,1] * 0.95

# define green line as the Asymptote

nls_line <- predict(nonlinreg1)

#plotting Asymptote (nls_line)

HabitReach95 <- approx(nls_line, df$days, xout = Asymp95)$y



# Now in GGplot 


ggplot(data=df,aes(x=days, y=score)) +
  geom_point()+

#HERE now from this intersect below, I would like to obtain the exact X-value

  geom_point(x = HabitReach95, y= Asymp95, aes(color="Intersect"), lwd=2) +






#this is the rest of ggplot code but I think it is not of interest for the described problem, but still just in case...

  geom_smooth(method=lm, aes(color="Linear Reg"), se=F) +
  geom_smooth(method="nls", formula=y~SSasymp(x, Asym, R0, lrc), aes(color="Non-Linear Reg"), se=F) +
  geom_hline(aes(color="Asymptote for non-linear Reg", yintercept=summary(nonlinreg1)$parameters[1,1])) +
  geom_hline(aes(color="Habit plateau at 95%", yintercept=Asymp95)) +
  xlab("Days of Experiment") + ylab("Automaticity Score Habit") +
  ggtitle("Test graph for participant") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  #ylim(0,49)+ # Actual graph or scale for experiment
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "purple", "orange", "blue", "red"), name="Legend")
```

Comment: It is very difficult for anyone to help just looking at the code. It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Very good Point! Okay let me try to simplify it....

Comment: Hope it ibecomes a bit clearer now... If there are still remaining questions, I will be happy to edit further

Answer (score 0):

OMg I am so stupid... I already calculate it with this line here!!!

```
HabitReach95 <- approx(nls_line, df$days, xout = Asymp95)$y
```

Haha can not believe it... well sometimes you don't see the forest for the trees!